# How to see what's in a session

Tags: systemd, proc, syslog, session

I'm seeing a lot of messages like this in syslog

```
Aug 31 16:28:38 server systemd[1]: Started Session c924093 of user buntu.                                
Aug 31 16:28:40 server systemd[1]: Started Session c924094 of user buntu.                                
Aug 31 16:28:41 server systemd[1]: Started Session c924095 of user buntu.                                
Aug 31 16:28:43 server systemd[1]: Started Session c924096 of user buntu.                                
Aug 31 16:28:44 server systemd[1]: Started Session c924097 of user buntu.
```

How can I see what's inside those sessions? Is there something in /proc I can look at?

Comment: What do you mean with *inside those session*? What information do you want to find?

Answer (score 2):

`systemctl status session-[session id].scope`

This will tell you what processes are running under that login session. That can be any kind of session, whether it be graphical, ssh, text based, etc. If `systemd` created the session, `status` will tell you what processes are running under it.

In your case you could use:

```
systemctl status session-c924093.scope
```

For the first one in `syslog`.

Comment: When I try that it always says this in the header.
 Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: Once the session exits (the person logs out) the session won't exist anymore.

Comment: You may be able to try `journalctl -u session-[ID].scope` to get an idea of what they did while they were there.

Comment: If I do that then it just shows that an ssh session was opened and then closed. If I use systemctl and catch it in time before it closes then it shows that an rsync is being done. The rsync is probably running on another computer that is copying over a file.